# Application not visible in taskbar when using Application.Run()

Tags: c#, .net, taskbar

I am creating a windows application using C#.Net. I am showing a form when starting an application using below code :

```
Form myForm = new MyForm();
Application.Run(myForm);
```

Application is not appearing in taskbar, but I know its running since I can navigate to the application window using Alt-TAB.

If I use `myForm.ShowDialog()`, application is visible in taskbar.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: `ShowInTaskbar` property is set to true for the form.
UPDATE2: `FormBorderStyle` is set to `None`

Comment: Did your form inherits from any class ?

Comment: Could it be something stupid, like if you use Windows7 it appears in group of other windows already opened ?

Comment: @Tigran : Well I don't think so windows 7 makes this stupid mistake.

Comment: @S.Amani - yes, it inherits from 'GenericForm' which has some default actions from Ok/Cancel buttons and stuff.

Comment: @Tigran - No, that is not it.

Comment: I recommend you to create a new project add new form inherits from  'GenericForm' without change anything in your parent class, then see what result you will get.

Comment: @S.amani that is not a mistake of windows, that is actually the way it works.

Comment: @Tigran : Windows 7 groups applications when there are more than one application with same behavior opened, not for all.

Comment: @Nishan : what happened ?! what did you get ?

Comment: @S.Amani I tried a simple case with just one Form inherited from GenericForm - it worked fine. So it is something else.

Comment: I suggest something is in your code that avoid it to show in taskbar. can you describe exactly what have you done in code, insert some code, maybe it helps us to see what exactly you did.

Answer (score 5):

Toggle `ShowInTaskbar` in your `form load` event with these two lines:

```
This.ShowInTaskbar = False
This.ShowInTaskbar = True
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Guess this happens when you inherit a class. 
This worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

Add Activate() in Form_Shown event.

Answer (score 1):

With .NET Framework 4.6.1, toggling:

```
this.ShowInTaskBar = false;
this.ShowInTaskBar = true;
```

causes `FormClosing` event being fired.

Calling `this.Activate()` in `Shown` event works properly.

In my case it was nonmodal form, called to be shown with `ShowDialog()`, but the request to create and show the form was sent from pipe. When executed by user's click on main form, everything was ok, form was shown and appeared on the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

You may not set an empty string as windows title during Form load.
This is what happened to me today (my window title is retrieved from a file that was missing, and so the window disappeared from the taskbar).